# integral of sin(x) to the power 2014

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

For a course in Complex Analysis we're tasked to find the integral of
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2 \pi} (\sin\theta)^{2014} d \theta
\end{align*}
but I'm a bit stumped so far on how to do this.

What I've done so far:

- First I tried to replace $ \sin \theta$ by $\frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}}{2i}$, but you still have this weird term $(e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta})^{2014}$ to deal with, so I guess that's not the correct way.
- Secondly I thought about intepreting this as the imaginary part of $e^{i \theta}$, but I get stuck on the 2014 power, so this method presents problems as well.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful, thank you!

Comment: Hint: Binomial theorem.

Comment: I assume you mean apply the Binomial theorem to $(e^{i \theta} - e^{- i \theta})^{2014}$ ?

Comment: Hint: $$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{imx} dx = \begin{cases}2\pi&m = 0\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: x @Roz: Yes. Most of the terms then disappear when you integrate.

Comment: Ah, that actually makes sense, let me work for a sec..

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: @HenningMakholm So, if I'm correct then the integral can be rewritten to $2^{-2014} \int_0^{2 \pi} \sum_{k = 0}^{2014} \binom{2014} {k} e^{(n - 2k) i \theta} d \theta$

Comment: which, using @achillehui's hint has only one non-zero term: k = 1007, so we get $2^{-2014} \binom{2014}{1007} \int_0^{2 \pi} 2 \pi d \theta = 4 \pi^2 2^{-2014} \binom{2014}{1007}$. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Rozemarijntje: Yes, except I think you have a factor of $2\pi$ too many. The $2\pi$ in Achille's hint comes from the integration limit; the _integrand_ itself in the $m=0$ case is just $1$.

Comment: Of course, I misread, stupid of me.. Thank you all for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=e^{i \theta}$; then the integral is equal to

$$\frac{-i}{(2 i)^{2014}} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} \left (z-z^{-1} \right )^{2014} = \frac{-i}{(2 i)^{2014}} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^{2015}} \left (z^2-1 \right )^{2014}$$

The easiest way to evaluate this integral is to use the residue theorem, which states that the integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the pole at the origin.  We could drive ourselves nuts taking huge derivatives, or we can simply seek out the coefficient of the $z^{2014}$ term in the numerator, which by the binomial theorem is easily deduced.  The integral is thus

$$i 2 \pi \frac{-i}{(2 i)^{2014}} (-1) \binom{2014}{1007} = \frac{\pi}{2^{2013}} \binom{2014}{1007}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT :**

Let
$$
I_n=\int\sin^n ax\ dx,
$$
then using integrating by parts, it is not difficult to obtain
$$
anI_n=-\sin^{n-1} ax\cos ax+a(n-1)I_{n-2}.
$$
It is called integration by reduction formula.

> Note that, if we use integration by reduction formula for $3$ or $4$ steps, you will see the pattern that leads to the result
>   $$
> \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^{2014} x\ dx=2\pi\cdot\frac{2013!!}{2014!!}.
> $$
>   I just don't get it why my answer got vote down without double-checking first. Maybe that was just an unintentionally mistake. just try to stay positive. **:)**

You can also write:
$$
\sin ax=\frac{e^{iax}-e^{-iax}}{2i}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\sin^n ax=\left(\frac{e^{iax}-e^{-iax}}{2i}\right)^n
$$
and then expand the term $\left(e^{iax}-e^{-iax}\right)^n$ using Binomial theorem. Perhaps using Binomial theorem would be a bit longer than using integration by reduction formula.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: Why do you put QED at the end of all your answers? Do you know what QED means?

Comment: @Oliver Does the QED sign in the end of my answer bother you? Is this forbidden putting the QED sign here? If so, I will not put it again. Indeed I know what it means. I just put it in the end of my answer as my 'signature'. :)

Comment: @Oliver do you know what QED means?? Why do you care what people put at the end of their solutions?  Tunk-Fey solution has many nice solutions he posts.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you Jeff. I thought it was forbidden here. I'm still learning & adapting here. It's just a matter of taste. **:)**